# Why doesn't the selected image from my scrollview get passed to the other view controller?

Tags: uiscrollview

Why doesn't the selected image from a scrollview get passed to the other view controller?

```
- (void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture{

    CGPoint touchPoint = [gesture locationInView:_scroller];

    int tapOnView = (touchPoint.x / 1024) + 1;

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%d.png", tapOnView];

    UIImage *photo = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    NSLog (@"the image selected is %@",imageName);

    PaintViewController *paintVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"paintViewController"];
    [paintVC.tempDrawImage setImage: photo];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:paintVC animated:YES];    
}
```

[link to my project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c99bpzw16oih9ex/pruebaScroll.zip)

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the method `tap` by the following method

```
- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture{

    CGPoint touchPoint = [gesture locationInView:scrollView];

    NSUInteger touchedPage = floorf(touchPoint.x / scrollView.frame.size.width);
    if ([imageArray count] > 1) {

        touchedPage = touchedPage % ([imageArray count] - 1);
    }

    //Push the image to another view
```